Restricting to region of interest in GEE
I'm using the following code to visualise and export a monthly mean of satellite data. How can I restrict the analysis to a small region? I tried creating a rectangular geometry and adding .filterBounds(geometry) on line 4 below, but the data returned is still global:
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2')
 .select('NO2_column_number_density')
 .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31')

var val_max = 0.0001;
var val_min = 0;
var band_viz = {
  min: val_min,
  max: val_max,
  opacity: 1.0,
  palette: ["black", "blue", "purple", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "red"]
};

Map.addLayer(collection.mean(), band_viz, 'no2');
Map.setCenter(175, -40, 5);
Export.image.toDrive(collection.mean())


You have to clip your image for the interestes region.Try this code. You can change your ROI by creating a geometry in GEE. You can also add a shapefile of your region if you have one.
// Define your geometry here. This is just an example.
// var roi = 
//     /* color: #98ff00 */
//     /* displayProperties: [
//       {
//         "type": "rectangle"
//       }
//     ] */
//     ee.Geometry.Polygon(
//         [[[-111.03914998209888, 44.990622008350144],
//           [-111.03914998209888, 40.99086938011925],
//           [-104.11776326334888, 40.99086938011925],
//           [-104.11776326334888, 44.990622008350144]]], null, false);

var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31')
  .mean();
var finalimage= image.clip(roi);
var val_max = 0.0001;
var val_min = 0;
var band_viz = {
  min: val_min,
  max: val_max,
  opacity: 1.0,
  palette: ["black", "blue", "purple", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "red"]
};
Map.centerObject(finalimage,11);
Map.addLayer(finalimage, band_viz, 'no2');

// Define export parameters
var exportParams = {
  image: finalimage,
  description: 'NO2_density',
  scale: 30,
  region: roi
};

// Export the image to Drive
Export.image.toDrive(exportParams);

